# Send a proactive message to user via api controller

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to make a reminder feature for a chat bot. I thought of using azure function to make an api post request when it matches a date. I made a controller with [this](https://github.com/jamesemann/bot-framework-v4-intro-dotnet-core/tree/master/demo9proactive) guide i found.

I tried it on bot emulator and found that it only works like this:
Run code and bot emulator then make a request on fiddler but nothing happens.
Then i stop running the code and run it again but not to restart the emulator.
Then i make a fiddler request again and now it successfully sends a proactive message. And i also cannot continue a dialog. What i want to achieve is when the proactive message is sent, the user can still continue the dialog if the user is in a middle of a dialog.

OnTurnAsync()

```
        var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        var filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "resume.json");
        File.WriteAllText(filepath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversationReference));
```

Controller

```
namespace BasicBot.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/callBack")]
    public class CallBackController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public CallBackController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            this._hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] ProactiveMessage message)
        {
            var filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "resume.json");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                var resumeJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                var resumeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(resumeJson);
                var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(resumeData.ServiceUrl));
                var message1 = resumeData.GetContinuationActivity().CreateReply($"Try send proactive message");
                await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message1);
                return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ProactiveMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you referenced the official Botbuilder-Samples [16.proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) sample? It should give you insight into how to setup your bot.

Comment: I have not migrated my codes to the new bot framework yet. because some features of my bot don't work on the new bot framework structure.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages) is the link to the older v3 proactive message sample. Hopefully it will help guide you some.

Comment: I am using V4 though the first one and not the latest which is kinda new in architecture. But thank you for helping me!